Why pyautogui cannot find my image saved as a screen?
I've just started coding, I've been training by myself for a few days and I'm facing a problem.
to resume: my script was working fine until this morning. I was working on correcting some problems when I wanted to try it again. What worked yesterday like click confirmation after clicked on ressource it no longer works today. It's not a button subject to shadows or textures in the game, it's a black-on-grey button, and the screen of this button is of very good quality.
Image confirmation recolting ressource
The problem is that pyautogui no longer seems to recognize it. I've changed the screen's png file and tweaked the lines of code, but there's nothing I can do. If you have any idea what's wrong, I'd love to hear from you. Thanks in advance
my script
Error message

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
